# Delete all rows that contain characters others than [A-Za-z0-9] in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I know i can select all rows that contain non-english characters using below query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE NOT username REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

How can I delete them using a single query now?

My results are more than 15000 rows so I can't select and drop them 30 by 30 takes so much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `SELECT` statement finds the rows you're looking for, in most cases you can delete the part before the `FROM` and replace it with `DELETE`.

With your example, this would be

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE NOT username REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```